# Deriving averages correctly in a PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, pivot

One of our managers has requested a report with a specific format with employee names as rows, Months of the year as columns, and average revenue per month per employee populating the cells. The dates will ultimately be replaced with @startdate and @enddate variables, but for the sake of building and testing I have hard coded one calendar year.  To accomplish this request I have created a PIVOT query, however my result set is incorrect and I seldom use PIVOT queries, so I am not knowledgeable enough to understand the problem, and I am hoping for some help from someone who uses them often.

First, here is my query that pulls the correct result set without the requested formatting:

```
select d.Name, AVG(gross), s.systemmonth, s.SYSTEMYEAR
from desk d, PAYMENTS s
where d.code = s.DESK
and s.ENTERED between '2017-08-01' and '2017-09-30'
group by name, s.SYSTEMMONTH, s.SYSTEMYEAR
order by name
```

A few rows of the result set:

```
Name    (No column name)    systemmonth SYSTEMYEAR
employee 1  221.5737        8           2017
employee 1  181.2476        9           2017
employee 2  161.62          9           2017
employee 2  321.9311        8           2017
employee 3  249.2245        9           2017
employee 4  328.1208        8           2017
employee 4  198.6748        9           2017
employee 5  76.4833         8           2017
employee 5  96.6896         9           2017
```

Now for my PIVOT query:

```
select name, [1] AS January, [2] AS February, [3] AS March, [4] AS April, 
[5] AS May, [6] AS June, [7] AS July, [8] AS August, [9] AS September, [10] 
AS October, [11] AS November, [12] AS December
from
(select d.Name, s.gross,  s.systemmonth, s.SYSTEMYEAR
from desk d, PAYMENTS s
where d.code = s.DESK
and s.ENTERED between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
group by name AS Employee, s.gross, s.SYSTEMMONTH, s.SYSTEMYEAR) a
PIVOT
(AVG(gross)
FOR systemmonth IN
([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
) AS pvt
order by name
```

The accompanying results, the averages are all incorrect (the NULL is correct however).  I've just included 2 months for ease of reading and comparison:

```
Employee    August    September 
employee 1  279.501   245.478   
employee 2  544.9648  235.9713  
employee 3  NULL      312.5366  
employee 4  403.1505  273.9044  
employee 5  129.8883  239.8701
```

Can anyone tell me why the averages in the PIVOT are not calculating correctly?  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: do you have a reporting tool that you will be using (which should handle the pivot if so) or are you just planning on running this query in the DB and copying the results to excel or something (and Excel can do a pivot too)?

Comment: Hi Thomas.  We use Visual Studio to build our reports, so basically copy and paste the query into the build wizard.  I honestly don't know if does that kind of manipulation, but its a good point and I'll look into it.

Comment: Then you are probably using SSRS in Visual Studio. Check out the Tablix functionality (table, list, matrix). A matrix will pivot your raw data out for you (you wouldn't even provide the pre-computed average, just the raw `gross` field) and then let your reporting tool aggregate everything for you. Should also make it easier and more dynamic when you end up adding your start and end parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing this line from your pivot query. You are grouping for no reason it seems.

```
group by name AS Employee, s.gross, s.SYSTEMMONTH, s.SYSTEMYEAR
```

You could also take your first query and pivot on that and your pivot aggregate would become `MAX` or `MIN` at that point because you will only ever have 1 row in the dataset for each employee/month combination.

Comment: Excellent call Thomas!  That fixed the problem.  It didn't even occur to me to remove that after needing it in my original query.  Thanks so much for the assist!